# Logging requests into database

Tags: database, security, web, logging, request

Should I log requests info (client ip, request status code, execution time etc.) in my web app into the database to analyse users behavoir and arised errors? And what info log for better experience?

Comment: It is very hard to answer this question exactly as there is an amount of context required to answer this effectively. We would need to understand why are you thinking about logging this data, what value would this data give you, how would your business be impacted without the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its often tempting to log lots of information, however I usually find that when I come to use it to answer a question it's often the case that the wrong piece of information has been recorded or only partially. Or it has been recorded but has not been stored in a usable way and takes further programming to turn the log into meaningful information.

So I would start with the question of what you want to see/find and log accordingly. Generally then logging capability can be expanded in the future as new issues/insights are required.

remember every time you log something you are slowing your application down. You are also using more disk space, no one is going to thank you for buying more disk / longer backups just because you have logged everything on every action.

I guess I would follow a train of thought a bit like:

1) What are you trying to find, if its an error you can predict then why not cater for it in your code to start with. If its usability what format does the data need to be in at at what points should it be recorded.

2) How long do you need it for, be sure to purge the logs after a period to conserve disk space.

3) Every element stored is a performance hit, might be small but for high number of transactions it adds up.

4) Be wary of privacy rules, an IP address may be considered as identifiable data, in which case you need to publish a data privacy policy (see point 2).

5) Consider using a flag to control logging on or off. Then you can use it at times of a known issue but not record everything always when not needed.